# Multiple SqPaymentForms in one webpage

Tags: square-connect

I am using Square credit card processing, I have to use two payment forms in same webpage one is for pickup payment and other for delivery payment.
I tried to integrate SqPaymentForm in my webpage i was successful for pickup payment. when it comes to delivery may be formwas loading twice and I have to enter all my card details twice in the form. How can i over come this problem?

```
 var paymentFormUserPickUp = new SqPaymentForm({
                        applicationId: ApplicationId,
                        inputClass: 'sq-input',
                        cardNumber: {
                            elementId: 'sq-card-numberup',
                            placeholder: 'Card Number'
                        },
                        cvv: {
                            elementId: 'sq-cvvup',
                            placeholder: 'CVV'
                        },
                        expirationDate: {
                            elementId: 'sq-expiration-dateup',
                            placeholder: 'MM/YY'
                        },
                        postalCode: {
                            elementId: 'sq-postal-codeup',
                            placeholder: 'Zip Code'
                        },
                        callbacks: {
                            cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
                                if (errors) {
                                    // handle errors
                                    var Errors;
                                    errors.forEach(function (error) {
                                        Errors += error.message + ",";
                                    });
                                    Errors.trimEnd(',');
                                    alert(Errors);
                                } else {
                                    alert(nonce);
                                    localStorage.setItem("Nonce", nonce);
                                }
                            },
                            unsupportedBrowserDetected: function () {
                                // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
                            }
                        }
                    });


var paymentFormUserDelivery = new SqPaymentForm({
                        applicationId: ApplicationId,
                        inputClass: 'sq-input',
                        cardNumber: {
                            elementId: 'sq-card-numberud',
                            placeholder: 'Card Number'
                        },
                        cvv: {
                            elementId: 'sq-cvvud',
                            placeholder: 'CVV'
                        },
                        expirationDate: {
                            elementId: 'sq-expiration-dateud',
                            placeholder: 'MM/YY'
                        },
                        postalCode: {
                            elementId: 'sq-postal-codeud',
                            placeholder: 'Zip Code'
                        },
                        callbacks: {
                            cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
                                if (errors) {
                                    // handle errors
                                    var Errors;
                                    errors.forEach(function (error) {
                                        Errors += error.message + ",";
                                    });
                                    Errors.trimEnd(',');
                                    alert(Errors);
                                } else {
                                    alert(nonce);
                                    localStorage.setItem("Nonce", nonce);
                                }
                            },
                            unsupportedBrowserDetected: function () {
                                // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for multiple forms for a single card input. Why does an order take both pickup and delivery payments? Do you have a sample page?

Comment: I don't have any sample page. Order will not take both pickup and delivery, only one will be allowed but the page contains both pickup payment form and delivery payment form. Once adding of items to the cart was completed user pick an option either pickup or delivery. according to that we will show a panels.

Comment: While the current impl doesn't support multiple forms, could you postpone the initialization of the form objects so only one is active at a time? The following is the pseudo code: 
`var pickupForm, deliveryForm

onPickupPanelShow: initPickupForm()
onDeliveryFormShow: initDeliveryForm()

initPickupForm() {
  if (deliveryForm) {
    deliveryForm.destroy()
    deliveryForm = null
  }
  pickupForm = new SqPaymentForm( ... )
}

initDeliveryForm() {
  if (pickupForm) {
    pickupForm.destroy();
    pickupForm = null
  }
  deliveryForm = new SqPaymentForm( ... )
}`